# Get records from last one year upto last date of previous month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get records from last one year and upto last date of provious month i.e. not including the current month. Here's my query:

```
SELECT `customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_date` 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE DATE(`customer_date`) <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
      AND DATE(customer_date) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

This query fetches records from 1 May, 2018 to 8 April 2019.

INTERVAL 1 MONTH fetches records 30 days ago. What I need to do something here?

I want to exclude current month records, so query should return records upto 30 April 2019. How do we do that?

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: I mean just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must correctly calculate the first and last days of range with help [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function. For example:

Calculate the first day of the range

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Output:

> 2018-05-01

Calculate last day of the range

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Output:

> 2019-04-30

The full query might look like:

```
SELECT `customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_date` 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE `customer_date` >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND `customer_date` <= SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Maxim

Answer (score 0):

To get data up to the previous month:

```
where customer_date < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day
```

Why?  First note that there is no function call on the `customer_date`.  So, this expression is index-compatible and can use an index.

Second, this structure works both for dates and date/times.  That is very handy, because it may not always be obvious if a column has a time component (people are not very good about naming columns to capture this information).

You claim that the "12 months" ago portion works.  That doesn't look correct to me.  For the complete logic:

```
where customer_date < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day and
      customer_date >= (curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day) - interval 1 year)
```

Comment: Seems to be a bit more complex. Maxim solution was easy to understand and fulfills my requirements. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_date` FROM `customers` WHERE
MONTH(`customer_date`) <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND 
MONTH(customer_date) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

hope this help